# Word to describe someone's childhood stories that are funny, at their funeral?

Tags: single-word-requests

My partner is writing a eulogy for his Mum. He is describing a time when she would share funny stories from her childhood. So here is the word we can't figure out.

> *I always knew I had Mum's Sense of humour. Mum would tell us her childhood stories. They were ?????*

The word should mean "funny unforgettable"

Comment: **Reminiscence**? **Anecdote**?

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard a single word for what you're referring to. You could say *funny recollection of her childhood*. (Anecdote and reminiscence don't often connote the funny part, I guess.)

Comment: My Dad was the consummate story-teller. I would say to my husband, (relatively new to the family) "Go over and listen... This story is a ***classic***."

Comment: There is nothing wrong with **funny and unforgettable**, nor do I think there is any single word that's the equivalent, let alone better. It's often impossible to find a single word that works as well as the combination of two.

Comment: Writing a eulogy isn't like writing a telegram where you want to hit the minimum number of words. It's far better to say more rather than less, speak from the heart, and express how you feel.

Answer (score 0):

"Heart-warming" may strike a sympathetic chord.  Check it out here: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/heart-warming

An anecdote is a short and usually amusing account of an incident, usually personal (according to my 1996 Collins English Dictionary).

Amusing recollections or amusing memories spring to mind, but amusing anecdotes is the best I can come up with.

As an example, at my brother's funeral, his children recounted several heart-warming accounts, anecdotal and designed to conjure up fond memories.

P.S. Hope the eulogy is well received.

Comment: Heart-warming, to me, is a story of orphan kittens that are found a good home. These "heart-warming stories" are rarely funny. Have you some reference that includes humour?

Comment: Working on it.  Heart-warming can also mean emotionally rewarding or uplifting, although I concede it isn't usually associated with humour.  Have to sign-off now and get dinner on so it may be tomorrow before I can respond.